# Navigation Title View Issue in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios11, ios-autolayout

I am facing an issue on Navigation bar items in iOS 11 as below screen shot and the two bar button also not executing any button actions.

[image]

It is working perfectly on iOS 10.x.x and below with same auto layouts and size.
Following screenshot is showing how custom Navigation bar IB implemented.
[image].

I tried with following codes too..

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
      [[self navigationController] navigationBar].prefersLargeTitles = NO;
      [[self navigationController] navigationItem].largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
   }
```

..but not helping. Please suggests me what's the issue here and how to fix (any autolayout issues ?).

Comment: Why aren't you using the right navigation item space?

Comment: Also check frame or size of the Navigation Title View (or its subview you call the View in Storyboard) maybe that is wrong size...

Comment: @Ladislav I changed the sizes and layout It solved the position problem. But still the button events are not executed in iOS 11 only?

Comment: How do you add NavigationTitleview to the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can customize in Right/Title Bar Items directly as in the following Gifs:

1-

[image]

2-

[image]

This way you can connect the buttons and receive actions normally.

Note: see gif number 1 then number 2.