# Right bar button is clickable outside of Navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am adding a right bar button in navigation bar but when i click out side of navigation bar as shown in picture below it get pressed i don't know why it is behaving like this. I have added this button from storyboard. [image]

Comment: i already described i have added it from storyboard.

Comment: can you put the project git URL to check the issue?

Comment: its a code privacy issue.

Comment: i have simply dragged and dropped it into navigation bar at rootViewController. Nothing more or less.

Comment: Here's a quick tutorial that might help you on how to add a navigation item in the navigation bar using storyboard 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46752677/4004429

Let me know if it helped fixing the problem

Comment: Debugging View Hierarchies will help you solve the problem. See this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: @Bilal its  fine in view debugger.

Comment: @AymanIbrahim well that is another topic i can't find anything helping at your provided link.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan do you drag a Bar Button Item into the right navigation item and change the image property and the problem still occurs ?

Comment: Select the navigation item in the View Hierarchies and you will see the bounds. Most probably it's because of the image you are using. What's the size of the email icon image? Does't it have any transparent area around?

Comment: its size is 10, 20 and 30 1x 2x and 3x respectively. i have clicked on it. its bounds are in navigation bar